# how to do echo of selected item using php

Tags: php, concatenation, ng-options

In a form after submitting the data, if i want to edit form the data in the form should be from database i have to echo the selected value from the database if data is present else it has to show the options to select the values from another table where these options are present

here is the code 
please correct it

```php
<select name="ccname" class="form-control form-color">

    <?php
    if(isset($storyData)) {
        echo '<option value="' . $storyData['ccname'] . '">' . $storyData['ccname'] . '</option>';
    }
    else{
        echo "<option value="">CCname</option>";
        foreach(getNames() as $ccname) 
            echo '<option value="'.$ccname.'">'.$ccname.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Punctuation and capitalization go a long way to making the question readable.

Comment: in the selected option you just need to put the `selected="selected"` attribute. So: `<option value="$ccname" selected="selected">$ccname</option>`.

Comment: i am looking for the first echo there is a mistake in concatenation operator so it is not executing if you can correct it please

Answer (score 0):

after working with concatenation operator finally debugged the code

here is the code 
that i corrected

```
<select name="ccname" class="form-control form-color">
                            ``<?php if(isset($storyData))
                            {
                            echo "<option value = '" . $storyData['ccname'] . "'>".$storyData['ccname']."</option>";
                            }
                            else{
                echo "<option value='1'>CCname</option>";

                     foreach(getNames() as $ccname) 
                        echo '<option value="'.$ccname.'">'.$ccname.'
                </option>';
            }
                    ?>
            </select>
```

Comment: echo "<option value='" . value . "'>".value."</option>"; so here the problem was the quotation marks closing and opening also the . operator always between <option value=""></option>while echoing the data we have to make sure we have not given space